# ¿Cómo puedo agregarle más espacio en disco a mi maquina virtual de Arch Linux?

Tags: virtualbox, archlinux

Estoy teniendo un problema, ya que yo uso Windows 10 y virtualicé Arch Linux usando VirtualBox. El problema es que le puse por error 10 GB de espacio al disco de almacenamiento de mi maquina virtual. la cuestión es que logré agrandarle el tamaño que le había asignado a la maquina virtual de 10 GB a 20 GB, pero el problema es que en mi Arch Linux no me aparece esa información y me aparece como si siguiese teniendo solo 10 GB.

Soy nuevo en Arch Linux, por lo que no sé muy bien que hacer. He visto si es que podía redimensionar mi partición y agrandarle de esa manera el espacio adicional en disco, pero el límite que me aparece son 10 GB.
Por favor ayúdenme a agrandar la memoria que le había asignado a mi maquina virtual sin perderla, ya que me costó bastante instalar Arch Linux.

Comment: ¿Memoria o disco? Si es disco, la solución es usar GParted desde un liveCD (que puedes configurar en las opciones de almacenamiento de la VM) y redimensionas las particiones. Si es memoria, el OS arranca con lo que VirtualBox le diga que tiene.

Comment: uhhhhh, genial. Si, era para el disco. Ahora mismo me pongo a intentar hacer eso. Te aviso si es que me funcionó

Comment: ¿Y cómo podría hacer para poder usar un GParted desde un liveCD en Arch Linux?

Comment: Lo intenté, pero no me aparece la memoria no asignada en el GParted. Creo que estoy haciendo algo mal XD jajajajaj

Comment: Si sigues diciendo memoria para hablar de disco, el dios de las distribuciones linux te va a castigar con un driver de video que nunca te va a funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTA: Antes de hacer nada, sácale un snapshot a tu VM por si dañas todo**. No, no te voy a explicar cómo, revísalo en la documentación de VirtualBox. Aquí sólo intentaré responder tu pregunta.

**NOTA 2: Para el futuro, la memoria es una cosa y el disco es otra cosa. Si mezclas los términos, no vas a recibir ayuda útil.**

Tienes que redimensionar la partición. Cuando instalaste tu distribución de Linux, usó lo que había para definir las particiones (equivale a que conectaras un nuevo disco duro... la tabla de particiones no tienen nada sobre ese disco nuevo y no hay direcciones de memoria que apunten allá).

Ahora hay que redimensionar la partición para que el OS pueda usarla. La idea es que uses algo como GParted que te permite editar fácilmente las particiones. NO puedes usarlo con el OS iniciado, porque no te va a dejar editar la partición montada (en uso, pues). Entonces, toca como un LiveCD, que cargue todo en memoria sin usar "el disco"

Ve al sitio de [GParted](https://gparted.org/download.php) y descarga el liveCD

[image: Sitio de descarga GParted]

Tienes que hacerlo "desde un LiveCD" (y ya veo que no entiendes bien cómo va esto). Entonces, detienes tu VM y vas a configuración

[image: VBox configuración]

Luego, en *Almacenamiento*, seleccionas la unidad óptica (lo que la VM ve como la unidad de CD/DVD) y buscas el LiveCD de GParted

[image: VBox Almacenamiento]

Y ahí seleccionas el ISO que descargaste al comienzo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cambia el orden de arranque de la VM, para que primero use el LiveCD (en *Sistema*). Si no marcas la opción, no la usa así esté de primera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le das OK para guardar todos estos cambios y luego inicias la VM. Te va a salir algo así. Le das Enter para usar la opción por defecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego te va a preguntar sobre el keymap, el idioma y cosas... puedes usar las opciones por defecto o puedes modificarlas a tu gusto. Finalmente iniciará una sesión gráfica y te mostrará el contenido de los discos en tu VM.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciona la partición que quieres modificar, clic derecho, redimensionar/mover y haz lo que necesites.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al final, usa el tick/chulito del menú principal para Aplicar los cambios, apaga la VM, quita el liveCD de la configuración de la VM (el que pusimos al comienzo) y arranca la VM normalmente.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. He intentado hacer exactamente lo que me dijiste, pero no he podido lograr agrandar  los GB del disco que le asigné originalmente a mi Arch Linux en VirtualBox. Lo curiosos es que en VirtualBox me aparece que la memoria del disco si se ha incrementado, pero en la maquina virtual de Arch Linux no me aparece en el disco que hayan GB sin asignar. Es decir, no puedo redimensionar en Arch Linux

Comment: @HeberAlturria No es claro dónde dices que "en virtualbox me aparece que el disco sí se ha incrementado". Por favor, edita la pregunta y AÑADE la información. Cómo agrandaste el disco? Cómo está definido. Si no añades eso, no hay respuesta posible